# Import ES6 module from http url in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am writing an ES6 module which depends on the other ES6 module specified with http url like this:

```
import { el, mount } from "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redom/3.26.0/redom.es.js";
const pElem = el("p") // definitely works in Javascript
```

When I tried to translate my module in Typescript, I got this error:

> Cannot find module 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redom/3.26.0/redom.es.js' or its corresponding type declarations.

I'm using `ts-watch` npm module to compile Typescript, and it works fine unless I don't use the `import` from `https://...`.

I also know that if I tried to import npm module (e.g. `import {el} from "redom"`) it works as well. But what I am writing is a module for web browser, not that of npm. With this reason, using `webpack` is not an option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import TypeScript Module from a Uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865445/import-typescript-module-from-a-uri)

Comment: It's close to my case. But I want to use ES6 import in my code, which currently results compilation error from Typescript. Is there a way to mute this error?

Comment: If you just want to mute typescript error, you can try this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBbA9sArhBByAFgFzwAcBnALgHpyAqLAKFtElgRXU3i0K3gG9b4B8AJaJCyGHnjAoeKPABmMZIg74iZSgHMheHGgBGAOjDK6g+CAAeYibyky5AX1rOgA

Comment: That's what I wanted to do! Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks to @acrazing's comment, I managed to resolve this problem. Here's how:

In a new ts file:

```
declare module 'https://*'
```

This mutes the error that Typescript compiler attempts to read type declaration.

If you want to access type declaration as a node dependency, paste this in a new ts file:

```
declare module 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redom/3.26.0/redom.es.js' {
    export * from 'redom'
}
```

and add `redom` dependency in package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "redom": "3.26.0",
    ...
  },
```

Then, type declaration is read from local `./node_modules` directory, VSCode recognizes the types as well.

Comment: This didn't do anything for me until I placed it in the `src` folder with the rest of my files, rather than in a separate top level `types` folder.  Honestly not sure why that mattered yet, probably some esoteric tsc resolution thing.  So, `<PROJECT>/src/types/redom.d.ts` rather than `<PROJECT>/types/redom.d.ts` for me.

Comment: Whups, looks like my issue was actually forgetting to set the TS compiler option `"moduleResolution": "node"`.

Answer (score 3):

`declare module 'https://*'` somehow doesn't work for me so I simply ignore it.

```
// @ts-ignore Import module
import { Foo } from "https://example.com/foo.ts";

// Now you can use Foo (considered any)
```