# how to import petite-vue as a typescript module?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, petite-vue

So far I've tried the following snippet on a `app.ts` script, but had no success to find out which cdn url I should point to, so I can import [petite-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue) as a typescript module.

```
import { createApp } from 'https://unpkg.com/petite-vue@0.4.1/?????'

PetiteVue.createApp({
    name: "Hello World"
}).mount("#div-id");
```

So, is there a direct cdn url to get petite-vue as a typescript module? If not, what is the best approach to get it working on my typescript code? Or is there a `.d.ts` somewhere to translate the javascript module available from unpkg.com to typescript? How should I use it?

Looking at github sources for petite-vue I found the following declaration inside [package.json](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue/blob/main/package.json), but I can't figure out how to use this piece of information.

```
"types": "./dist/types/index.d.ts"
```

(I'm brand new to the typescript world and also to the whole javascript modules ecosystem)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62124572/import-es6-module-from-http-url-in-typescript

Comment: "I'm brand new to the typescript world" - consider doing this the conventional way, i.e. by installing packages locally. You'll need to have build an app any way for TS, it doesn't make much sense to stick to CDN packages for that.

Comment: @EstusFlask I'm avoiding the build approach because my project already has a tricky build process running Gradle on multiple deploy servers where I have low privileges to install packages, etc. The simplest approach I could find is to transcript .ts files in development time (counting on IDE plugins for that) and have the transcripted .js files as part of the source code. No "package install" needed for that yet and I hope I can keep it this way.

Comment: "I have low privileges to install packages, etc." - if you're able to run TS, you may be able to run the rest of build process. It requires Node/NPM at deploy time. This goes without saying for deploying modern JS apps. In the worst case you'll need to build  the app locally and deploy a prebuilt bundle, this doesn't differ much from what you're doing in IDE. What you're trying to do is far from the simplest approach, just because this is advanced topic that you won't find guides for. If you're new to JS tooling, this is definitely a footgun. Consider Vite or Vue CLI for commonly used TS setup

Comment: Any luck figuring this out?

Comment: @Terry not at all

Comment: I misread what you wanted actually, but I think you just want https://unpkg.com/petite-vue?module if you want it as module.  I thought you wanted the types to use when doing IIFE development.  Then you also wouldn't use `PetiteVue.` prefix, just use `createApp` directly.