# Using URL imports in TypeScript project with Deno, getting "Cannot find module ts(2307)" IDE warning

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, deno

I just started using TypeScript with Deno. I have never done any front end development work before.

Since I am using Deno I need to import everything as a URL import from a CDN. In my TS file, I have

```js
import { LitElement, customElement, html } from 'https://cdn.pika.dev/lit-element';
```

My IDE gives me a warning about how it cannot find the module:

```
Cannot find module 'https://cdn.pika.dev/lit-element' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Could not find module "https://cdn.pika.dev/lit-element" locally.Deno Language Server(1005)
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "experimentalDecorators": true
    }
}
```

The program runs fine, but the IDE error is really annoying and I would like to resolve it. As a new developer these warnings are important for figuring things out so having false positives sucks :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import TypeScript Module from a Uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865445/import-typescript-module-from-a-uri)

Comment: you need to add `.ts` at the end of the import url in `deno`

Comment: I replaced with `https://cdn.skypack.dev/pin/lit-element@v2.4.0-1XOpe9DTEoAR5DmPqDi1/min/lit-element.js`, still getting `Cannot find module 'https://cdn.pika.dev/lit-element' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
`

Answer (score 1):

That's because those packages aren't cached locally. I had the same issue and it
disappears after I hit

```
deno run my-file.ts
```

After it Deno will download or those packages and cache them. Error should disappear then.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and this does not fix it